# Email client, "Mutt", is not sending messages?

Tags: email, smtp, mutt

I recently installed mutt on my computer... I configured my muttrc to be like this:

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes
set imap_user = 'username@gmail.com'
set imap_pass = 'password'
set from = 'username@gmail.com'
set use_from = yes
set folder = imaps://username@imap.gmail.com/
set spoolfile = imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX
set postponed="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Drafts"
set record = +sent
set header_cache = "~/.mutt/cache/headers"
set message_cachedir = "~/.mutt/cache/bodies"
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificates"
set smtp_url="smtp://username@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
set smtp_pass="password"
set move = no
set imap_keepalive = 900
set editor = 'vim'
```

When I try to compose and send an email, I get this error:

```
SMTP session failed: read error
```

Please tell me what is wrong (or how I could check the error message).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo, the line starting `set smtp_url` should read:

```
set smtp_url="smtp://username@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
```

**s**mtp, not **f**mtp

Comment: Thanks for reminding me but the problem is still there (I still have the problem).

Comment: @BooHoo did you try the alternate port 587? e.g. check here: https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/send-mail-gmail-mutt.html

Comment: alternatively you can try msmtp: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MuttAndGmail

Answer (score 0):

If you are using port 465, that's SMTP over SSL/TLS. You should use "smtp**s**://" instead of "smtp://".

If you want to use regular SMTP (ie. first plaintext connection, then switch to encrypted via STARTTLS), use port 587, not 465.